# Python requests usage to replace a cURL call

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I want to replace this call

```
curl [url] -u user:pw -d param1='p1' -d param2='p2'
```

with a simple requests.post call in python.
I've tried something like this:

```
_params={'param1': 'p1', 'param2':'p2'}
response_adding = requests.post(url, params=_params, auth=(user, pw))
```

I got a HTTP OK (200) back, but nothing happens.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Can you try to print response_adding.content?

Comment: The response is "<Response [200]>" 
If i make the cURL call, i get back a long json object, also with status 200, but with more details, and also the portal i was calling is making the changes i wanted to make. With requests, nothing is changing.

Comment: Also, i'm using requests.put for another calls, with url,headers,data,auth
and it's working properly.